GeoServer GeoFence extension from a different GeoServer instance
I am using the docker GeoServer image from kartoza and I currently have this setup: one GeoServer acting as "master" and one GeoServer acting as "node". The master has GeoFence-Server plugin installed and it works fine on that container, but the node has GeoFence because I want to use the server from the master. What GeoFence service URL should I place in the node such that it works? Or is it possible to do what I am asking?  Node GeoServer GeoFence Admin Page
I tried different URLs I found on the internet but none of them worked (with the port 9191 from master, with geofence/remoting/RuleReader, with /rest/geofence, but none of them worked.
